# How to use polars.lit in groupby aggregation context

Tags: python, python-polars

Basically, I want to calculate sum of powers for a constant.

As an illustration:

```
import polars as pl

c = 2

df = pl.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3]})

>>> df.select(pl.lit(c).pow(pl.col("a")).sum())

literal
---
f64
14.0
```

However when I try to do the same thing in a groupby agg context, I got an error:

```
import polars as pl

c = 2

df = pl.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], "b": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]})

>>> df.groupby("b").agg(pl.lit(c).pow(pl.col("a")).sum())

Error originated in experssion: '2i32.pow([col("a")])'
```

One (temp) way I can make it work is to append a column beforehand on df such as

```
df = df.with_columns(pl.lit(c).alias("c"))
```

But it is not clean as there may be an existing column with name "c" (or whatever alias I give) in original df, which could cause column name collision.

I am sure there could be better and cleaner way to to this. But how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you may need to [`.repeat_by`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.repeat_by.html#polars.Expr.repeat_by) to get the lengths to match.

```
df.groupby("b").agg(
    pl.lit(c).repeat_by("a").pow(pl.col("a")).sum()
)
```

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────┬─────────┐
│ b   ┆ literal │
│ --- ┆ ---     │
│ i64 ┆ f64     │
╞═════╪═════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 14.0    │
│ 2   ┆ 14.0    │
└─────┴─────────┘
```

Comment: It turned out the repeat_by is very slow in large dataframe groupby context.

Comment: @Keptain Ah okay. Maybe you can try `pl.lit(c).repeat_by(pl.count())` instead to see if there is a difference. Although, I think adding it as a column first will be the most efficient approach, but you have the problem of needing to guarantee a unique name as you've mentioned.