# How to add a temp column for calculation purposes without column name conflict

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a custom function which does some data cleaning job. For efficiency considerations, I cache some results in the middle and remove them at the end.

Below is an illustration for my function at hand:

```
import polars as pl


def clean_data(df, cols):
    return (
        df.with_columns(pl.mean(col).alias(f"__{col}_mean") for col in cols)
        .with_columns(
            pl.when(pl.col(col) < pl.col(f"__{col}_mean") * 3 / 4)
            .then(pl.col(f"__{col}_mean") * 3 / 4)
            .when(pl.col(col) > pl.col(f"__{col}_mean") * 5 / 4)
            .then(pl.col(f"__{col}_mean") * 5 / 4)
            .otherwise(pl.col(col))
            .alias(col)
            for col in cols
        )
        .select(pl.exclude(f"__{col}_mean" for col in cols))
    )
```

The code works fine for normal inputs:

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 28],
        "a2": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    }
)

clean_data(df, ["a", "a2"])

shape: (7, 2)
┌──────────┬─────┐
│ a        ┆ a2  │
│ ---      ┆ --- │
│ f64      ┆ f64 │
╞══════════╪═════╡
│ 5.892857 ┆ 3.0 │
│ 5.892857 ┆ 3.0 │
│ 5.892857 ┆ 3.0 │
│ 5.892857 ┆ 4.0 │
│ 5.892857 ┆ 5.0 │
│ 9.821429 ┆ 5.0 │
│ 9.821429 ┆ 5.0 │
└──────────┴─────┘
```

However, there is a possibility that my cached columns conflicts with columns existing in user's inputs, for example

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 28],
        "a2": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
        "__a_mean": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    }
)

clean_data(df, ["a", "a2"])

shape: (7, 2)
┌──────────┬─────┐
│ a        ┆ a2  │
│ ---      ┆ --- │
│ f64      ┆ f64 │
╞══════════╪═════╡
│ 5.892857 ┆ 3.0 │
│ 5.892857 ┆ 3.0 │
│ 5.892857 ┆ 3.0 │
│ 5.892857 ┆ 4.0 │
│ 5.892857 ┆ 5.0 │
│ 9.821429 ┆ 5.0 │
│ 9.821429 ┆ 5.0 │
└──────────┴─────┘
```

The result masked the column `__a_mean` in the original dataframe.

My question is that is there a way that when I append temp columns in the middle of calculations, I can make sure or generate temp column names which does not exist in the original dataframe dataframe?

Or is there a way to implement my custom function above without caching any results and with no sacrifcing performance?

Comment: Not an answer to your question - but have you timed against just using `pl.col() < pl.col(col).mean()` instead of adding the temp columns? Testing locally, that runs faster for me. Polars does caching/optimizing internally e.g.  when/then branches execute in parallel, so it's also worth measuring if you haven't.

Comment: For large dataframe and operations involving 'over' by some groups (the example function does not show groupby/over just for simplicity), the current implementation with explicit caching showed here is 2.5x faster than not.

Comment: Also, with explicit caching, I can get much faster performance when ```mean``` here is replaced by some other complicated ufunc. So, I do think explicit caching helps but just don't know how to avoid column names clashing.

Comment: Yes someone also asked about creating "unique" temp column names in a recent question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75835399/how-to-use-polars-lit-in-groupby-aggregation-context - perhaps it's something that could be added to polars if a current solution doesn't exist.

Comment: Worth creating a github feature request?

Comment: Not quite sure whether there is a similar feature in pandas.

Comment: Hm yes, perhaps the reason this doesn't already exist is because it's a "bad idea"? My idea was to use `.clone` and `.update` - if you'd like to measure that approach to see if it slows things down or not, it would interesting to know.

Comment: This seems like a simple fix of just changing `f"__{col}_mean"` to something with more nonsense in it like `f"__{col}_meanfgblr89ru58t69e9ghfjkawef5t85yhjbhnkjhadfharkjh785"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how much overhead this would add:

You could use [`.clone()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.clone.html#polars-dataframe-clone) in combination with [`.update()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.update.html#polars.DataFrame.update)

```
def clean_data(df, cols):
    return (
        df.update(
            df.clone()
            .with_columns(pl.mean(col).alias(f"__{col}_mean") for col in cols)
            .with_columns(
                pl.when(pl.col(col) < pl.col(f"__{col}_mean") * 3 / 4)
                .then(pl.col(f"__{col}_mean") * 3 / 4)
                .when(pl.col(col) > pl.col(f"__{col}_mean") * 5 / 4)
                .then(pl.col(f"__{col}_mean") * 5 / 4)
                .otherwise(pl.col(col))
                .alias(col)
                for col in cols
            )
            .select(pl.exclude(f"__{col}_mean" for col in cols))
        )
    )
```

The `.clone` docs says it's a cheap operation, `.update` performs a `.join` internally.

```
>>> clean_data(df, ["a", "a2"])
shape: (7, 3)
┌──────────┬─────┬──────────┐
│ a        ┆ a2  ┆ __a_mean │
│ ---      ┆ --- ┆ ---      │
│ f64      ┆ f64 ┆ i64      │
╞══════════╪═════╪══════════╡
│ 5.892857 ┆ 3.0 ┆ 1        │
│ 5.892857 ┆ 3.0 ┆ 1        │
│ 5.892857 ┆ 3.0 ┆ 1        │
│ 5.892857 ┆ 4.0 ┆ 1        │
│ 5.892857 ┆ 5.0 ┆ 1        │
│ 9.821429 ┆ 5.0 ┆ 1        │
│ 9.821429 ┆ 5.0 ┆ 1        │
└──────────┴─────┴──────────┘
```

Perhaps explictly storing the clone in a variable would make the code more self-documenting.

```
def clean_data(df, cols):
    means = [ f"__{col}_mean" for col in cols ]
    mean_cols = dict(zip(cols, means))
    
    formula = lambda x, y: (
       pl.when(x < y * 3 / 4)
         .then(y * 3 / 4)
         .when(x > y * 5 / 4)
         .then(y * 5 / 4)
         .otherwise(x)
    )

    mean_df = df.clone()
    mean_df = (
       mean_df
       .with_columns(
          pl.mean(col).alias(mean) for col, mean in mean_cols.items())
       .with_columns(
          formula(x = pl.col(col), y = pl.col(mean)).alias(col) 
          for col, mean in mean_cols.items())
       .select(pl.exclude(*means))
    )

    return df.update(mean_df)
```